# Vendor won't sell X-01 armor

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing the game for a while (level 64) and I cannot buy x01 power armor for rowdy at the atom cats garage anymore. I have bought some pieces from her in the past but cannot do so anymore. I also cannot wait at the bench in the garage anymore, as that has worked before in the past as well. However, there is a brotherhood Lancer at the garage that will not move nor be killed. Any assistance  would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking for an X-01 armor? Maybe [this](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/X-01_power_armor) will help.

Comment: You could make that an answer NVZ.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you, but I've done the same thing--used her to farm X-01 parts. I think thats what the OP is wanting to do.